# I'm getting error in my c++ code! & How to find determinant and inverse of matrix in c++?

Tags: c++, matrix, calculator, inverse

I'm trying make matrix calculator. in which i almost done every operation which required in matrix. So now i'm trying to code to find determinant and inverse of matrix, but im getting error like :-  **argument of type "int" is incompatible with parameter of type "double(*)[100]"**

I'm using Visual Studio 2019.

```
int dat(int n, double mat[100][100]) //function
{
    Matrix s1;
    double det = 0;
    int p, r, c, subi, i, j, subj;
    int submat[10][10];
    s1.getmatrix1();
    r = c = n;
    if (n == 2)
        return((mat[0][0] * mat[1][1]) * (mat[1][0] * mat[0][1]));
    else
    {
        for (p = 0; p < n; p++)
        {
            subi = 0;
            for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
            {
                subj = 0;
                for (j = 0; j < n; j++)
                {
                    if (j == c)
                        continue;
                    submat[subi][subj] = mat[i][j];
                    subj++;
                }
                subi++;
            }
            det = det + (pow(-1, p) * mat[0][p] * dat(n - 1, submat[i][j])); //here at 'submat' i'm getting that error. 
        }
    }
    return 0;
};
```

Comment: What's not clear about the error message? *Obviously* you cannot pass a `int` to a function expecting `double(*)[100]`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a couple of problems with your code beside the compilation error.

1) Since `dat` expects the second argument to be an array, the function call should be:

```
det = det + (pow(-1, p) * mat[0][p] * dat(n - 1, submat));
```

2) The determinant of a 2x2 matrix should be computed as follows:

```
return((mat[0][0] * mat[1][1]) - (mat[1][0] * mat[0][1]));
```

3) `int submat[10][10]` should be `double submat[100][100]` since it needs to be able to contain (almost) as many elements as `mat` and should store the same data type.

4) The return value should be `double` instead of `int`.

5) The condition `if (j == c)` should be `if (j == p)` since `p` is the row/column that we want to exclude.

6) The `i` loop should start at 1 since we do not include the first row/column in the submatrix.

7) `s1`, `r`, and `c` are never used and can be removed.

8) The return value should be `det`

Note: The time complexity of this algorithm, called [Laplace Expansion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace_expansion), is `O(n!)` (see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace_expansion#Computational_expense)). If you want to use it for production code, I strongly recommend using a more efficient algorithm that are based on matrix decomposition.

Answer (score 2):

You're passing the (i,j)th element of submat to dat().

submat[i][j] is an int. But the dat() function expects a 2-d array of doubles (with the second dimension being 100, so even replacing it with just

```
dat(n-1, submat)
```

won't be correct